# Create Salesforce KB article using API

Tags: api

According to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_API_intro.htm, it is not possible to create a kb article via the REST API. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The knowledge article data model is polymorphic in nature .

Hence the creation of the knowledge article process is similar to creation of any other record except we have articletype appended by __kav to get the object name .

Hence to create Initial version in REST API i would use the same calls as i use for other object

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm

You will have to insert knowledge article using REST API as below

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm

```
curl kav/">https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/FAQ_kav/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 

@newarticle.json"
{
"summary" : "Sample article"
//Include various fields here 
}
```

Remember to set up REST API you will first have to OAUTH with salesforce or obtain session ID using login() call