# How to create Knowledge Article in Salesforce using REST API

Tags: api, rest, knowledge

In response to the question : [Create Salesforce KB article using API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122062/create-salesforce-kb-article-using-api)

I used the curl call that is provided and I run into the below error :

```
[
    {
        "message": "entity type cannot be inserted: FAQ",
        "errorCode": "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY",
        "fields": []
    } 
]
```

My request in Postman is :

**POST** https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/FAQ__kav

**Headers**
Authorization : Bearer 
Content-Type : application/json

**Body**
{
    "summary" : "This is a test KB article"
}

Appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution using the WorkBench tool provided by Salesforce :
https://workbench.developerforce.com/

To create an Article, you would need to pass the **`articleType`** with the suffix **`__kav`** as shown below :

`POST /services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Support_Community__kav`

Body: ( mandatory parameters -> summary,title,urlName )

```
{
 "summary":"Summary for the Article",
 "title":"Title",
 "urlName":"Url Name fo Testing"
}
```

*Note*: `Support_Community` is the `ArticleType` for the article you are creating.